# Shortest path while going through all required points

Tags: python, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star, maze

How would I go about making the following program? I need help making a plan for the logic, as I can program it. I just don't know how to find solutions that can also go back on previously visited spaces, as most algorithms don't allow that.

I have tried implementing A* algorithm and Dijkstra's algorithm, however like I said, I'm not sure how to modify these to allow it to go back on previously visited spaces.

> Write a program that navigates a 4 by 4 maze by hopping from one spot to another.
>
> - Can not land on spaces that are "|", "—", "I", "=", or ".".
> - Can jump over "|" and "—".
> - Can not jump over "I" or "=".
> - Can not jump diagonally.
> - Can go back on spaces that have already been landed on.
> - Can only jump over one space at a time.
> - Must start on space "S".
> - Must end on space "E".
> - Must land on all spaces that are "X" before landing on space "E".
> - Ends when space "E" is landed on.
> - Must return the shortest possible path.
>
> Output the coordinates of each space that the program lands on in the order that they are landed on.
>
> ```
> maze = [
>     ["O","|","E","I","X","I","O"],
>     ["—",".","=",".","—",".","—"],
>     ["O","|","O","|","O","|","O"],
>     ["=",".","—",".","=",".","—"],
>     ["X","|","O","I","O","|","X"],
>     ["—",".","=",".","—",".","="],
>     ["O","|","S","|","O","|","O"],
> ]
> ```

Here's what the 2D array above looks like:
[image: Maze]

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Split the problem into hitting each X. Within each individual segment, the shortest path will not backtrack, but you may backtrack when comparing all segments. You'll have to figure out how you want to optimize the order of X's you want to travel.

Comment: Optimizing the order of X's is known as the traveling salesman problem, which is not an easy problem when there are a large number of X's. If there are only a few X's, the brute force solution is to try every possible order.